# Unable to pass current_user.name as an attribute for comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments

Workaround for the below:

```
    <%= f.label :Commenter %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :commenter, :value => current_user.name %>
```

This works for passing the username to the commenter attribute without having to type it in - with the addded bonus of being able to edit it if necessary!

---

I am trying to make my website show the name of the user who created a comment. In order to do this, I would like the commenter (attribute of comment) to be assigned as current_user.name.

comment has attributes commenter, body, and expdate.

Is it possible to pass current_user.name to the comment.create method through the form?

I've tried this:

```
<div>
    <%= form_for([@project, @project.comments.build]) do |f| %>
        <br>

        **<%= @commenter = current_user.name %>**

        <%= f.label :Comment %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
        <br>
        <%= f.label :'Expected Date' %><br>
        <%= f.date_select :expdate %>
        <br>
        <br>
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Where I assigned the commenter attribute to be current_user. Does this not pass that to the create method?

I have also tried assigning it in the comments_controller like this:

```
def create
    **@comment.commenter = current_user.name**
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @comment = @project.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to project_path(@project)
end
```

But I get an error complaining that commenter is not a defined method.

Both of the methods I tried don't allow me to create a comment, does anyone have any ideas of how I might do this?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in the create method in your controller:

```
@commenter = current_user.name
```

It's that simple. And if you need to access the commenter name in your view, add this to your comment class:

```
def commenter(user)
  user.name
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= @comment.commenter(current_user) %>
```

If you're trying to set @comment.commenter, you will have to define the relation between the two models. Not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but more info about Active Record associations can be found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Ah thanks so much, this method has allowed me to post the comments! However, when I call them in the view like so:

`code`
<table>
 <p>
  <td style="width: 11%;"> <i> <%= comment.created_at.strftime("%d %m %y") %> </i>  </td>  
  
  <td style="width: 15%;"> <b><%=  comment.commenter %>

The users name doesn't appear - do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: You could put that commenter method in your comment class instead of a view helper if you need to. I added an edit with a solution that should work for you.

Comment: Ah, it doesn't work for some reason - I would post more code but it doesnt format properly  in this comment box! Thanks for helping

commenter is an attribute of comment btw

Comment: Ah, I've tried everything you added, but I'm getting the error 'undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass' when I try posting a comment. The error is pointing at <td style="width: 15%;"> <b><%=  @commenter.name %></b>

Comment: You need to do @comment.commenter. Sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately I checked the database and it looks like the commenter column is set to null for all of these comments, meaning that the @commenter = current_user.name didn't work, so neither will the view code! thanks for all the help!

Comment: As long as your user table has a name column, the commenter code should work. It isn't even looking for a commenter column.

Comment: Found a workaround - I just added a commenter field on the form, and let it auto-fill to current_user.name:   <%= f.label :Commenter %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :commenter, :value => current_user.name %> 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In the controller, like this:

```
def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @comment = @project.comments.create(comment_params)
  @comment.commenter = current_user.name
  redirect_to project_path(@project)
end
```

And in the view:

```
<% @project.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= comment.body  %></td>
    <td><%= comment.commenter %></td>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This also worked, thanks! Still can't figure out how to now call the commenter attribute in the view though

Comment: Ok, I dont understand the question :(